# SVG SMIL animations are back and well and it should be informed in older posts

Tags: discussion

The GitHub pages about SVG SMIL animations give a clear warning in posts that handle the "deprecation" topic (see image) stating that SMIL´s current status is not deprecated.
[image: The warning github gives on topics related to the depracation of SMIL animations in SVG]
This warning should be included in this site too, on pages like the following:
[Convert SVG SMIL animation to CSS animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351488/convert-svg-smil-animation-to-css-animation)

[Why is SVG SMIL animation not supported by IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926432/why-is-svg-smil-animation-not-supported-by-internet-explorer)

I suggest the administrators manage all keywords relating SMIL deprecation and add the warning to the (older) posts that have the keyword.

Comment: Chrome 45 was out in 2015. Do we really need to inform people of something that happened briefly more than 8 years ago?

Comment: I suggest we first update every question mentioning ``Internet Explorer`` with a line like _Internet Explorer is dead_

Comment: I mean... i'd love to have such a feature that allowed placing such notices on highly upvoted answers specifically for noting serious problems with the answer, but who gets to decide which highly-voted answers are... "wrong" or "out of date" enough to warrant such a notification? As it is we can't do anything with these answers but watch them continue to rise in score, a decade after they were deemed wrong/incorrect/out of date via comments.

Comment: I just looked at our tag info https://stackoverflow.com/tags/smil/info and it doesn't say anything about it being deprecated and/or undeprecated. So I guess we're all good then. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 7):

Given that someone who wants to animate SVG would likely be pulling up [a canonical source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL) to do so, and given that this page is the very page you are also referencing to, I don't *really* see a lot of impetus to try to "change" anything here on Stack Overflow.

If you could point to a few questions that still say that this is deprecated, the right thing to do would be to provide a concise answer that illustrates the OP's question answered with SVG SMIL, rather than just running around and saying, "It's not deprecated anymore!"

One of these things is highly constructive and ensures that we have lasting answer value.
The other is just us running around with our heads cut off, which isn't constructive.